# Allow Apache to write into locally synched docker volume

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN rm /var/log/apache2/access.log
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod deflate
RUN a2enmod headers
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  www:
    build: .
    ports: 
        - "8001:80"
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html/
    networks:
        - default
```

I have a folder within `www` that's called `photos`. It's at `www/photos`. I want to write files to it using my php upload function. I'm getting permission denied errors due to the fact that php-apache doesn't have write access to the volume. How to give apache write access?

Comment: Can you share which exact directory your php code is referring, as inside the docker container, the volume with be named as /var/www/html and not not /www

Comment: The file writing to disc is at docker-container: `/var/www/html/controllers/file.php`

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the directory on your host system, maybe guests do not have permissions to write. If necessary, change them using `chmod`:

```
chmod 766 -R your/directory/
```

Also, you can specify the permission to write inside your docker in a specified mounted volume by adding `:rw` (for read/write) at the end of the line:

```
- ./www:/var/www/html/:rw
```

Since this should be the default value it is not necessary to use it and should not be part of your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve it. Still getting returned 0 from $file_put_contents.

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid. It should be chmod 766 (6 meaning read and write). I changed it in the answer.

Comment: @TimDau Did this help you with your problem?

Comment: No sorry it didn't.